# magento ajax add to cart button will not work with secure https

Tags: ajax, addtocart, https, secure

I have enabled secure cart in our magento site[htttp = > https] . After that, add to cart buttons are not working. My theme has custom ajax add-to-cart button.
If I manually enter product detail page with https, the add to cart button works. But, 
if i disable ajax add to cart module than "add to cart" button will work.
demo url : http://videomergerapp.com/tollyjoy-baby-rattle-baby-play-pink-blue.html
i wanted this add to cart button to work with https enable in the site.

this is our view.phtml = http://pastebin.com/z6b05cCn

Comment: Sorry without some more information you will prob not get a good answer. May guess is that your Ajax is trying to load something from a secure page into a non secure page and fixing this will solve your issue as pointed out when you mentioned it working with https.

Comment: @DavidManners i updated the question ,let me know if you need any other part of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+J) you can see there are many errors on your page.

For example it's giving a 404 not found error for jQuery. So you need to add jQuery (maybe you just need to fix the path or the permissions)

And there are permission denied messages

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource

There seems to be problems with your tracking code (cross domain request)

There are also images missing.

Try adding the missing code and images. Turn off the tracking to test, then you could read posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: i iwll try this.....